Assistance Needed with AD Account Login Issue on File Vault-Enabled Mac
I hope this message finds you well.
I recently set up a Mac computer for a user in my office, as per their request. This is the only Mac on our network. I managed to bind it to our Active Directory without any issues, but now I’m encountering a problem. I can only log in with an AD account if I first log in with the local admin account. If I try to log in directly with an AD account after starting or rebooting the Mac, it doesn’t work. In Addition to this, I have enabled the Mobile Account for this user.
It seems this issue is related to FileVault, but our company policy requires us to encrypt computers, so I had to activate it. I’ve noticed there are some scripts, but I’m not familiar with Mac computers and I’m unsure how to use them.
Could someone please provide a step-by-step solution to this problem? I’m quite new to the Mac environment and would appreciate any guidance.
Thank you very much!
